# Split array as grid view in template Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an array of images and I want to display them as grid 10x10 (table). How can I implement that?

I've tried something like that, but it's wrong syntax:

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let avatar of avatars; let i = index">
            <ng-container *ngIf="i % 10 === 0 && i === 0">
                <tr>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <img class="img-avatar img-avatar48" [src]="avatar.avatarUri" [alt]="avatar.keywords" />
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="i % 10 === 0">
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: You don't want to use `table`. Look at using css `flexbox` and give each item `width: 10%`

Comment: No, I want to use datatables further for paging and search.So, I need a table.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added an answer which should achieve what you're after

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to chunk your data into arrays for each row, then use nested `*ngFor` loops to iterate over them. This can be achieved with a custom pipe

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of avatars | chunk: 10)">
    <td *ngFor="let avatar of row">
      <img class="img-avatar img-avatar48" [src]="avatar.avatarUri" [alt]="avatar.keywords" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `chunk` pipe can either use lodash [`_.chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/#chunk), or natively shown below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'chunk'
})
export class ChunkPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, n: number): any {
        return this.chunk(value, n);
    }

    chunk(arr, n) {
        let newArr = [];
        let nestedArr = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
            nestedArr.push(arr[i - 1]);
            if (i % n === 0) {
                newArr.push(nestedArr);
                nestedArr = [];
            }
        }
        if (nestedArr.length > 0) {
            newArr.push(nestedArr);
        }
        return newArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with async method of getting avatars.

Comment: oh, you didn't mention anything about `async`. Try converting `chunk` into a pipe and add it to the pipe chain. e.g. `*ngFor="let row of avatars | async | chunk:10"`

Answer (score -1):

your code contain extra `tr` do it like this

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let avatar of avatars; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="i % 10 === 0 && i === 0">
        <tr>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container>
        <td class="text-center">
            <img class="img-avatar img-avatar48" [src]="avatar.avatarUri" [alt]="avatar.keywords" />
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="i % 10 === 0">
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Did you check that this code compiles? It doesn't work for me

Comment: no , i did't check the code , it seems like there is error so posted here as answer, @ChristopherMoore